# Laravel Gate::any() returns reverted value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am defining gate in my code like this

```
    Gate::define('fullAccess',function ($user){
        return $user->id == 1;
    });
    Gate::define('manager',function ($user){
        return $user->type == User::TYPE_MANAGER;
    });
```

then in contoller I am checking if user has access

```
 public function __construct()
 {
     if(!Gate::any(['fullAccess','manager'])){
         abort(403);
     }
 }
```

But there is a problem:

```
 if(!Gate::any(['fullAccess','manager'])){
     //returns true
 }
 if(Gate::any(['fullAccess','manager'])){
     //returns false
 }
```

I'm absolutly sure my ID equals 1, and I think `any()` function must return **true** if at least one access action is available for curent user. Am I missing something?

I've tried `none` function also, and it works the same way

```
 if(Gate::none(['fullAccess','manager'])){
    //returns true;
 }
```

Comment: Just a random thought, could id be that you check it too early? The constructor of the controller may execute before the gates are defined etc.

Comment: @PavelLint yep, you are right. I replaced access checking to `callAction`, and now it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @PavelLint can you write this as answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've stated in the comment, checking things in a constructor is usually not safe and can result in unexpected order of execution. The solution for the OP's problem is to move the access check out from constructor to some controller function or elsewhere. Cheers :)

**UPD** with code example:
You override callAction method to check access before every action in controller

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    if(Gate::none(['fullAccess','manager'])){
        abort(403);
    }
    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters); 
}
```